# How to return a html page when user send a post request in Django Rest framework

Tags: django, django-rest-framework

i want to return a HTML page with value posted posted by user in django restframework

Model i have created is

```
class DetailView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset= Detail.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DetailSerializer

@action(methods=['GET'],detail=False)  
def get(self,request):
    first_name= request.POST.get("first_name")
    last_name = request.POST.get("last_name")
    return redirect ('index.html/')
```

url:
     router = routers.DefaultRouter()
     router.register('detail',views.DetailView)

index.html:
     {{first_name}}
     {{last_name}}

i want to automatically return a html page with value posted by them

Answer (score 0):

I think that has to be defined in the post method, instead of the get method. I assume that you want to post data given by a form. That would be an applicable way in my eyes:

**views.py**

```
class DetailView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    form_class = PersonalDataForm # defined in forms.py
    view_template = 'index.html'

def post(self, request, *args, **kwargs):
    form = self.form_class(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        personal_data = {}
        first_name = form.cleaned_data['first_name']
        personal_data['first_name'] = first_name
        last_name = form.cleaned_data['last_name']
        personal_data['last_name'] = last_name            

        return render(request, self.view_template, {'form': form, 'personal_data': personal_data}
```

**index.html**

```
<form action="" method="POST">
    {% csrf_token %}
    {{ form.first_name }}
    {{ form.last_name }}
    <button type="submit" id="submit-button">save</button>
</form>

{{ personal_data.first_name }}
{{ personal_data.last_name }}
```

You may want to hide the form if the user sends a GET request. You can do that by wrapping the wohle form into an if-clause like {% if valid_data_submitted %} ... {% endif %}

**forms.py**

```
class PersonalDataForm(forms.ModelForm):
    first_name = forms.CharField()
    last_name = forms.CharField()

    def save(self, commit=True):
        self.instance.first_name = first_name
        self.instance.last_name = last_name
        return super(PersonalDataForm, self).save(commit)

    class Meta:
        model: models.Detail
```

That might be a first approach. For further explanations I need to know how the data will be posted by the user.

Comment: Hi thanks for your response ,i am new to django , actually i am building an API , i will receive data from another server , i want to pass that data to my html page , then i have return a html page with their name.

Answer (score 0):

I think you should just change the `renderer_classes` attribute in your view set it to `TemplateHTMLRenderer`.

[document link](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/renderers/#templatehtmlrenderer)

but if I were you I would prefer user the django class base view.
I used it in my previous project alongside django rest-framework it was perfect.
[django class-base view](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/)

Comment: Hi i have a doubt , will it directly pass the post value and return a html page ?? sorry i am new to django.

Comment: but if I were you I would prefer user the django class base view.
I used it in my previous project alongside django rest-framework it was perfect.

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/class-based-views/

Comment: @shiva24 yes it will do this and beside this you can make an viewset from django viewsets to expose html , I think this is better.